# Different output of `find | xargs ls` for the same command on different Ubuntu versions

Tags: find, ls, xargs

I have two Ubuntu installations:

A: `14.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-77-generic x86_64)`

B: `14.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-61-generic x86_64)`

I'm running the following command:

```
find . -name "nosuch.file" -print0 | xargs -0 ls
```

(the real command is more complex, but I managed to narrow it down to this).
There is no file `nosuch.file` in the current directory or subdirectories.

On server A the command produces empty output as I expected.

On server B the command produces the listing of the current directory (where I run the command).

On both servers running just `find . -name "nosuch.file" -print0` produces empty output.

On both servers the same version of `find`, `xargs` and `ls` is installed:

```
$ find --version
find (GNU findutils) 4.4.2
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by Eric B. Decker, James Youngman, and Kevin Dalley.
Built using GNU gnulib version e5573b1bad88bfabcda181b9e0125fb0c52b7d3b
Features enabled: D_TYPE O_NOFOLLOW(enabled) LEAF_OPTIMISATION FTS() CBO(level=0)

$ xargs --version
xargs (GNU findutils) 4.4.2
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by Eric B. Decker, James Youngman, and Kevin Dalley.
Built using GNU gnulib version e5573b1bad88bfabcda181b9e0125fb0c52b7d3b

$ ls --version
ls (GNU coreutils) 8.21
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by Richard M. Stallman and David MacKenzie.
```

Why would the command behave differently? What can I do to achieve consistent behaviour as on server A (empty output for no found files)?

Comment: Does `xargs` have an alias defined which includes the `-r` / `--no-run-if-empty` option? If so, that would result in no output.

Comment: `find . -name "nosuch.file" -print0 | hexdump -C` might be informative as to the exact output of the `find` on both systems.

Comment: @AnthonyGeoghegan - there is no alias for `xargs`

Comment: @thrig - `find . -name "nosuch.file" -print0 | hexdump -C` produces empty result on both systems

Comment: Sorry to ask the obvious question, but is the directory where you run the command on Server A empty (or contains only hidden files/directories)?

Comment: @AdamMichalik , can you try to execute `find | xargs` construction, but specify full path to binaries? e.g. `/usr/bin/find ... | /usr/bin/xargs -0 ls`?

Comment: Same shell, same shell options?

Comment: It might be useful to run edit the question to include the output of `type -a xargs` on both servers as there's a chance that a function or a script with that name that acts as a wrapper for the actual `xargs` command.

Comment: The surprising behavior is server B. With empty input, `xargs -0 ls` should run `ls` once with no argument, and thus display the content of the current directory. What is the content of the current directory on B? Does the behavior change if you run the command in a different directory? Does the behavior change if you run it from a shell started with `env -i PATH=/bin:/usr/bin bash`?

Comment: If you simplify the command to `xargs -0 ls < /dev/null`, do you still get the same (inconsistent) behavior?

Comment: @steeldriver @Gilles - thanks for hitting the nail of my stupidity on the head... I was so focused on the commands that I ignored the simple fact that on server B I was calling it in a directory with some files in it and on server A - in a newly created, empty one. Using `xargs -r` presents the desired behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*“What can I do to achieve consistent behaviour as on server A (empty output for no found files)?“*

To achieve this behaviour with `xargs`, you can use the `-r` / `--no-run-if-empty` option so that the specified command is not run if no filenames are passed to it. From the *man page*:

> If the standard input does not contain any nonblanks, do not run the
>   command.  Normally, the command is run once even if there is no input.

Note that this option is a feature of GNU `xargs` and is not standard, i.e., specified by POSIX.